# Arduino-uno sending email with Hotmail

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I want to get emails read from a Hotmail account using an Arduino Uno. Is there a way to do it with SSL or is there a way to disable SSL?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
// Use comments to enable or disable this define for debug messages
#define DEBUG_POP
// Use comments to enable or disable the deleting of the mail
#define ENABLE_DELETE_POP


// The mac address must be an unique number
// A mac generator is used:
//   http://www.miniwebtool.com/mac-address-generator/
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0x36, 0x5F, 0x0A, 0x19, 0x83 };
// change network settings to yours
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 117);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);


// Set the server POP3 address, the port, the user and password.
// The POP3 mail server is something like this: 
//     mail.yourdomain.com, pop.yourdomain.com, pop3.yourdomain.com
// Using PROGMEM for these causes a fail when trying to connect and log in.
const char pop_server[] = "pop3.live.com";
const int  pop_port = 995;
const char pop_user[] = "xxxxxx@hotmail.com";
const char pop_pass[] = "xxxxxx";


// The number of milliseconds timeout for parseInt() and find().
// The response time for the Server can still be 10 seconds.
#define POP_TIMEOUT 10
#define POP_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT 1000


EthernetClient client;


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(F("\nArduino POP3 email reader"));

    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     // the system led is used for testing

    // When the Ethernet Shield is used, there is also a SD card connected
    // to the SPI bus. Disable the SD card with chip select at pin 4.
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);


    // Start Ethernet. Use only the 'mac' parameter for DHCP
    // Use 'mac' and 'ip' parameters for static IP address.
    //  Ethernet.begin( mac, ip);
    //  Ethernet.begin( mac, ip, gateway, gateway, subnet);
    if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP.");
        // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
        while (1);
    }
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, gateway, subnet);
    // print your local IP address.
    Serial.println(F("Ethernet started."));
    Serial.print(F("Local IP = "));
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

    Serial.println(F("Press 'c' to check mail."));
}


void loop()
{
    // Create a buffer to receive the commands in (that is the Subject of the mail).
    char buffer[32];

    byte inChar = Serial.read();
    if (inChar == 'c')
    {
        // The getEmail gets the text of the mail Subject into the buffer.
        // The valid number of received characters are returned.
        // If the return value is < 0, it is an error.
        int n = getEmail(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if (n < 0)
        {
            Serial.print(F("Email POP3 failed, error = "));
            Serial.println(n);
        }
        else
        {
            if (n == 0)
            {
                Serial.println(F("Ready, nothing to do."));
            }
            else
            {
                // 'n' is > 0, a command received.
                Serial.print(F("Email checked, Command = \""));
                Serial.print(buffer);
                Serial.println(F("\""));


                // Check the commands.
                //
                // At this moment, a single command 'L' is used to set system led on or off.
                //    L=1   (set led on)
                //    L=0   (set led off)
                if (buffer[0] == 'L' && buffer[1] == '=')
                {
                    digitalWrite(13, buffer[2] == '0' ? LOW : HIGH);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


// getEmail
// --------
// Find an email on a mail server, using POP3.
// The Subject should start with "ARDUINO " and the text
// after that is copied into pBuf.
// 
// The data in pBuf is only valid if the return value is not an error
// (an error is return value less than zero).
//
int getEmail(char *pBuf, int nBufSize)
{
    // nBytes is the number of bytes that is returned by getEmail.
    int nBytes = 0;

    // Connect to server
    // client.connect returns '1' if okay, or negative number if error.
    //    SUCCESS 1
    //    0     (error, unknown timeout, perhaps an error in the library)
    //    TIMED_OUT -1
    //    INVALID_SERVER -2
    //    TRUNCATED -3
    //    INVALID_RESPONSE -4
    //    -5    (there is no mail server at that IP address and port)
    // The string for the server must be a normal string in sram, no PROGMEM allowed.
    int nError = client.connect(pop_server, pop_port);

    // During testing, a value of zero was sometimes returned.
    // This is not according to the documentation and it is an error.
    // Therefor the non-error value '0' is turned into a negative number to
    // indicate an error.
    if (nError == 0)
        return(-200);

    // Only a value of 1 is okay.
    if (nError != 1)
        return(nError);

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("connected"));
    //Serial.println(nError);
#endif
    // The server should respond with "+OK" and maybe more text after that.
    // Check if "+OK" can be read.
    // The parameter 'true' is to read also everything after the "+OK".
    if (!readOk(true))
        return -102;

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("command USER"));
#endif
    client.print(F("USER "));
    client.println(pop_user);
    if (!readOk(true))
        return -103;

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("command PASS"));
#endif
    client.print(F("PASS "));
    client.println(pop_pass);
    if (!readOk(true))
        return -104;

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("command STAT"));
#endif  
    client.println(F("STAT"));
    if (!readOk(false))
        return -105;

    // The whole line was like this: "+OK 3 15343"
    // It means that 3 emails are waiting with a total size of 15343.
    // At this moment, the "+OK" is read, but nothing else.
    // Check if there is a space after "+OK".
    char c = client.read();
    if (c != ' ')
        return -106;

    client.setTimeout(POP_TIMEOUT);       // set timeout lower for parseInt
    // Read the number of emails that are on the server.
    int nMails = client.parseInt();
    client.setTimeout(POP_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);  // restore timeout to 1 second

    // Read the remaining of the response to STAT.
    readRemaining();

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.print(F("Number of emails="));
    Serial.println(nMails);
#endif

    // Test if there are emails waiting.
    if (nMails == 0)
    {
        // No emails, but no error. Set buffer to empty string.
        nBytes = 0;               // the returned value
        pBuf[0] = '\0';           // set empty string
    }
    else if (nMails > 0)
    {
        // emails are waiting.
        // Scan the emails until the first is found with the keyword "ARDUINO " at the
        // beginning of the "Subject: ".

        boolean found_and_ready = false;
        for (int nMailNumber = 1; nMailNumber <= nMails && !found_and_ready; nMailNumber++)
        {
            // The command RETR <x> gets the whole mail.
            // The command TOP <x> <size> gets the header plus 'size' of the body.

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
            Serial.print(F("command TOP "));
            Serial.print(nMailNumber);
            Serial.println(F(" 0"));
#endif    
            client.print(F("TOP "));
            client.print(nMailNumber);
            client.println(F(" 0"));

            // Use readOk with parameter 'false' to stop reading after "+OK".
            if (!readOk(false))
                return -107;
            // The header of the email is waiting to be read, use the Stream.find() to look for the Subject.
            // The text "Subject: " should be at the beginning of a line, but that is not tested.
            // The first found text "Subject: " is assumed to be the real subject.
            // I have checked many years of emails, and the text is always "Subject: ", and never "SUBJECT: ".
            // At the moment, it is not possible to use the F() macro for Stream.find
            // Only the email that starts with "ARDUINO " at the start of the Subject is used.

            client.setTimeout(POP_TIMEOUT);      // set short timeout for find().
            // find() returns true if found and false if not.
            boolean foundsubject = client.find("Subject: ARDUINO ");
            client.setTimeout(POP_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);   // restore timeout to 1 second

            if (foundsubject)
            {
#ifdef DEBUG_POP
                Serial.println(F("Found an email for me"));
#endif        

                // Read the remaining subject (that is the command for the Arduino) into a buffer.
                // Every line from the mail server should end with CR + LF, 
                // but to be sure, both CR and LF are checked.
                // Alternative:
                //    client.readBytesUntil('\r', pBuf, nBufSize);

                // The last position in the buffer is reserved for the zero terminator.
                // So read data until (nBufSize-1).
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < (nBufSize - 1) && client.available(); i++)
                {
                    char c = client.read();
                    if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
                        break;
                    pBuf[i] = c;
                }
                // Add zero terminator
                pBuf[i] = '\0';
                nBytes = i;     // the number of received bytes is returned by the getEmail() function.

                // More text of the header could be following the Subject.
                // That is read and disregarded.
                readRemaining();

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
                Serial.print(F("Subject = \"ARDUINO "));
                Serial.print(pBuf);
                Serial.println(F("\""));
#endif

#ifdef ENABLE_DELETE_POP
                // Delete the just read message.
#ifdef DEBUG_POP
                Serial.print(F("command DELE "));
                Serial.println(nMailNumber);
#endif    
                client.print(F("DELE "));
                client.println(nMailNumber);
                if (!readOk(true))
                    return -108;
#endif

                // Everything is okay, the mail is read and deleted.
                // Ready for now, don't process the remaining emails.
                found_and_ready = true;
            }
            else
            {
#ifdef DEBUG_POP
                Serial.println(F("No ARDUINO keyword in subject"));
#endif        
                // This email has no "Subject: ARDUINO ".
                // But the remaining text has still to be read and disregarded.
                readRemaining();
            }
        }
    }

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("Sending QUIT"));
#endif  
    client.println(F("QUIT"));

    // After "QUIT", the server still respons with "+OK",
    // but after that, the connection might get lost.
    // So don't read everything after "+OK" (use parameter 'false' for readOk).
    if (!readOk(false))
        return -109;

    client.stop();

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("normally disconnected"));
#endif

    return(nBytes);
}


// Read the response from the mail server.
// That is "+OK" if everything is okay.
// Parameter 'readAll' is to read every character after the "+OK".
boolean readOk(boolean readAll)
{
    // Check the response "+OK" from the mail server
    // In most cases that is followed by a space and more text, but not always.
    // In case of an error the text "-ERR" is received.

    int loopCount = 0;
    char bufOk[4];
    Serial.print("Connected: ");
    Serial.println(client.connected());

    Serial.print("Client Available: ");
    Serial.println(client.available());
    // Wait for response of mail server, with a timout.
    while (!client.available())
    {
        delay(1);
        loopCount++;

        // if nothing received for 10 seconds, timeout
        if (loopCount > 10000)
        {
            client.stop();
#ifdef DEBUG_POP
            Serial.println(F("\nTimeout"));
#endif      
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Read the first three bytes.
    client.readBytes(bufOk, 3);

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.write(bufOk, 3);
    Serial.println();
#endif

    // Is it "+OK" ?
    if (strncmp(bufOk, "+OK", 3) != 0)
    {
        popFail();
        return false;
    }

    // When the text after "+OK" is not needed, everything
    // else can be read and disregarded 
    // (or shown in the serial monitor during debugging).
    if (readAll)
        readRemaining();

    return true;
}


void readRemaining()
{
    // This function is called after checking the "+OK".
    // It reads everything from the server, until no more text is
    // available.

    while (client.available())
    {
        char c = client.read();
#ifdef DEBUG_POP_EXTRA   
        Serial.print(c);
#endif    
    }
    return;
}


void popFail()
{
    int loopCount = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("popFail"));
#endif

    while (!client.available())
    {
        delay(1);
        loopCount++;

        // if nothing received for 10 seconds, timeout
        if (loopCount > 10000)
        {
            client.stop();
#ifdef DEBUG_POP
            Serial.println(F("\nTimeout"));
#endif      
            return;
        }
    }

    client.stop();

#ifdef DEBUG_POP
    Serial.println(F("disconnected due to fail"));
#endif  
}
```

Output:

```
Arduino POP3 email reader
Ethernet started.
Local IP = 192.168.1.117
Press 'c' to check mail.
connected
Connected: 1
Client Active: 0

Timeout
Email POP3 failed, error = -102
```

Comment: Your title says it's about **sending** mail, while the code only contains code for **receiving** mail

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail doesn't provide a non-encrypted POP3 service, which would normally run on port 110.

You have no choice but to use the SSL service.  However, you can't.  Or not easily.  SSL is quite a heavy protocol and it is highly doubtful the little Uno is capable of even coming close to being able to work with it.

The Due might have a chance, but again, unlikely.

You would be best off using a computer (server) to check the emails for you and provide a "digest" of information to the Uno instead.

Comment: A Due certainly has the resources (memory) to do it, though the challenge may be in finding/creating an implementation.  Something with networking on board and an existing library might be easier and more cost effective - for example, a raspberry pi (though at the cost of a more delicate writable-filesystem OS installation).  The idea of using an additional server as a proxy to help out is a good one though, if the unsecured nature of the communication to/from that server is acceptable.